# Homomorphism of fields

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

if $\mathbb{K} $ and $\mathbb{L} $ are two finite fields what are the conditions on their cardinals for an homomorphism of fields between them to exists ?

Thank you !

Comment: You should probably call the two fields different things. Do you know that a homomorphism of fields is always injective? Do you know what the possible cardinalities of a finite field are?

Comment: Oh yes of course was supposed to be an L. Yes i know how to show the first thing and i know that the every finite field has a cardinal that is a power $r \geq 1$ of a prime number $p$. I know as well that every finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with cardinal $q=p^r$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Since every homomorphism of fields is injective we must have Card$\mathbb{K} \leq $Card$ \mathbb{L}$

Comment: Yes. Now ask yourself if you have an injective homomorphism what does it say about the characteristics of the two fields?

Comment: I think that i can even say that there exists a sub field $\mathbb{K'}$ of $\mathbb{L}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$

Comment: If their caracteristic is the same $=p$ and their cardinals are different with Card$\mathbb{K}=q=p^r$ we can extend $\mathbb{K}$ to $\mathbb{L}$ if $\exists s \in \mathbb{N^*} $ such that Card$\mathbb{L}=q^{sr}$ is this correct ?

Comment: But what would happen if their caracteristic are different lets say with $\mathbb{F_2}$ and $\mathbb{F_3}$ is it possible for an homomorphism of fields to exists bewtween them ? I think this is not allowed by definition since they do not extend anything.

Comment: Ok i think i understand if the caracteristics are the same but if they are not like i said in $\mathbb{F_2}$ and $\mathbb{F_3}$ can we say anything ?

Comment: Suppose you have a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{K}\to\mathbb{L}$ and $char(\mathbb{K})=p$. Then you have $0=\phi(p) = p\cdot\phi(1)=p$. So $\mathbb{L}$ also has characteristic $p$.

Comment: I see, so a homomorphisme between $\mathbb{F_2}$ and $\mathbb{F_3}$ is not possible.